# Parsing a string containing "\" in Racket

Tags: windows, racket, filepath

I am trying to extract tokens from a Windows path string that contains "\".

I have tried string-split and string->list, but one of the path elements starts with a "d", so I get a "read: unknown escape sequence \d in string" error.

Edit: The paths have the form: "\\aaaa\bbbb\cccc\dddd\eeee....". I need to extract, for example, the "eeee" part. The "string->" functions choke on the "dddd" element, with the above error. On Windows 7, Racket 5.3.3. For example : (string-split path), (string->list path)

Comment: How are you building this string? You should be using the path-specific procedures of Racket, such as for example `(build-path "c:" "Documents" "data.txt")`, `(split-path)`and so on. Also, note that to have a \ in a string you need to put it twice because \ is an escape character.

Comment: Also see `explode-path` and maybe `string->some-system-path` and `some-system-path->string`. Otherwise, we need more details: Code example? Are you running the code _on_ Windows, or not?

Comment: @vince If you use `build-path` and `explode-path` then your program automatically works on OS X and Linux too.

Answer (score 0):

Backslash is used as escape in strings. If you do `(read-line)` and enter one backslash the result is `"\\"`.

For hardcoded strings to test your programs you need to write like this `"\\\\aaaa\\bbbb\\..."`